# Making a div width (in percentages) fill its container div as other elements stack down?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm using the following CSS declarations:

```
.hentry,
.no-results {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1.625em;
    position: relative;
    width: 32%;
    max-width: 260px;
    min-width: 130px;
}
```

to archive this:

[image]

[image]

It is basically, a fluid layout except for the thumbnails in the middle (they are only partially fluid). I realized that the only way to make elements stack down is to define their width (in this case `min-width`).

Now, when the browser's window reaches this size:

[image]

There is space left on the right.

I was wondering if it is possible to make the images fill that space on the right?

**EDIT:** Should I just define the width of the divs according to trends in screen resolution (e.g. ipad, android, iphone)?

Comment: Maybe you'd want to check out this http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/smart-columns-w-css-jquery/ Demo: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/smart-columns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I em not sure what are you trying to achieve , but i em guessing you are trying to get everything aligned no matter the size of the screen .

You can use a padding with a negative margin in a "overflow hidden" div :
Ex :

```
/* wrapper around the text divs */ 
 ParentDIV {
width:100% ;
overflow:hidden ;
float:left
}

/* child divs for text */ 
Child1, Child2 , Child3 {
width:33% ; 
padding-bottom : 600px ;
margin-bottom  : -600px ; 
float:left
}

/* image div for images */ 
Imagewrap {
width:100% ; 
float:left
clear: both ; 
}
```

The html would look something like :

```
<div class="ParentDIV">
    <div class="Child1">
       <div class="Imagewrap"><img1></div>
       <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Child2">
       <div class="Imagewrap"><img2></div>
       <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Child3">
       <div class="Imagewrap"><img3></div>
       <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This setup will keep everything aligned . As for the picture give it a fluid width i think in your case 100% would do . Remember a fluid width on a picture will scale the picture up or down depending on the screen resolution . So it's not a perfect fix .